# VBA Excel save .xlsx file with the flexible name

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to save my file with the flexible name, which will change as the cell value changes.

The one answer is here:

[Save a file with a name that corresponds to a cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433489/save-a-file-with-a-name-that-corresponds-to-a-cell-value)

however, I want also some fixed part of the name, which won't change unlike the part described in the query above.

Basing on this solution I tried to write something as follows:

```
Sub Save ()
Dim name As String, Custom_Name As String

name = Range("A2").Value
Custom_Name = "NBU" & name & "- Opportunity list.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Custom_Name
```

In the effect, I am getting an error:

**This extension cannot be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the File name text box or select a different type file by changing the Save as type.**

I would like to have this file in the .xlsx extension.

[Excel VBA - save as with .xlsx extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747121/excel-vba-save-as-with-xlsx-extension)

The answer above doesn't really match to my situation.
It will be vital to remove all form control buttons in the newly saved file, when possible.

Thanks & Regards,

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code only set the  name to be used when you intend to save a workbook. Do you have a piece of code in order to make the saving? I don't like looking to other codes which does not do what you need. Can you clearly explain what do you wont your code to do? `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Custom_Name` wouldn't be enough?

Comment: I have added your piece of code. Sorry about it I completely forgot this snippet. Now I am getting an error. I updated my query with the missing part of the code.
My file name is Opportunity v1.0.xslm if it can help at some point. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Transform your line `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Custom_Name` in   `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Custom_Name, FileFormat:= xlWorkbookDefault`. But, of course, you must have a string in your `Range("A2")` cell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no action in the routine listed to save the file. It just simply takes the contents of a cell and creates a string with wrapped values.

I am not totally sure of what your goal is, but you need to add the action from the second link you provided. [Workbook.SaveAs Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas).

See the code below for a working example that I created to test.

```
Public Sub Save()
    Dim name As String, Custom_Name As String

    name = Range("A2").Value
    Custom_Name = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NBU" & name & " - Opportunity list.xlsx"

    'Disable alert when saving
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Save the workbook.
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Custom_Name, FileFormat:=51

End Sub
```

**You should note that after this code has executed, you will now be in the newly created file. This is not an export.**

Test this and let me know if you have any questions. *There are a few things that seem to be unnecessary in your code, but we can address those if you find this answers your first issue.*

## Edit:

I would also call out specifically then worksheet with the range as well.

`name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")`

Comment: I would use the cell A2 to full name the file though. There is no good reason to "Hard-Code" the prefix and suffix in the VBA code. You could just do it all in the formula in the cell.

Comment: It's also a way, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You said the file name is 'Opportunity v1.0.xslm'.  Would it have macros?  My version of Excel complains about using .xlsx if there is code in the workbook.

Comment: Basically I would like to save the macro-free workbook. This is why I want it in the .xslx version.