# VBA Excel saving the file in the folder created by Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to save my file in the folder created by...excel macro.

The process of vba excel folder creation has been presented here:

[Create a folder and sub folder in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803834/create-a-folder-and-sub-folder-in-excel-vba)

Following it, I have assigned it to my situation:

```
 Sub Createfolder ()
     Dim fso As Object
     Dim fldrtitle As String
     Dim flrdrname As String
     Dim fldrpath As String

     Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
     fldrtitle = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
     fldrname = "Pre-planning NBU " & fldrtitle
     fldrpath = "H:\ProfileV2\Desktop\Pre planning NBU\ Alex list new\" & fldrname
     If not fso.FolderExists(fldrpath) Then
         fso.Createfolder (fldrpath)
     End If
 End Sub
```

Where the folder has been created. 
My way to saving the file, according to the [previous query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285948/vba-excel-save-xlsx-file-with-the-flexible-name) looks as follows:

```
Sub Save()
    Dim name As String, Custom_Name As String

    name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    Custom_Name = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NBU " & name & " - Opportunity list.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Custom_name, FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

Now, I tried to combine them together at some point, where the way 1 was:

```
Sub Save()
    Call Createfolder

    Dim name As String, Custom_Name As String

    name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    Custom_Name = ThisWorkbook.Path & Createfolder & "NBU " & name & " - Opportunity list.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Custom_name, FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

Here I am getting error:
**Expected Function or variable**

what I understood, as I cannot fetch the external macro inside the code.

Afterwards I tried another way:

```
 Sub Savetofolder ()
     Dim fso As Object
     Dim fldrtitle As String
     Dim flrdrname As String
     Dim fldrpath As String
     Dim name As String, Custom_Name As String

     Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
     fldrtitle = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
     fldrname = "Pre-planning NBU " & fldrtitle
     fldrpath = "H:\ProfileV2\Desktop\Pre planning NBU\ Alex list new\" & fldrname
     If not fso.FolderExists(fldrpath) Then
         fso.Createfolder (fldrpath)
     End If

 'name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
     Custom_Name = ThisWorkbook.Path & Createfolder & "NBU " & fldrtitle & " - Opportunity list.xlsx"
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Custom_name, FileFormat:=51
 End Sub
```

I switched off the `name` variable, because it's the same as `fldrtitle`.

In the result my file is saved next to the created folder as per in the picture below:

[image]

Is there any chance to get it saved INSIDE this folder?

Comment: What line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: What that `Createfolder` from the workbook name creation, wants to be?

Comment: fldrpath = "H:\ProfileV2\Desktop\Pre planning NBU\ Alex list new\" & fldrname 
This is my folder name.
Once I use the 2nd solution, there is no error.
In the 1st solution the error is thrown at this line:
Custom_Name = ThisWorkbook.Path & Createfolder & "NBU " & name & " - Opportunity list.xlsx"

Comment: Like I previously said `& Createfolder &` makes no sense... `Createfolder` is not a function to return a path. Even if it would be, in conjunction with `ThisWorkbook.Path` it makes no sense  even more... When you need building a path which looks peculiar, try `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path & Createfolder & "NBU " & fldrtitle & " - Opportunity list.xlsx"` and see what it returns.

Comment: OK, How about the last code - my 2nd approach? Because the file is saved just next to the folder I believe, that the mismatch in the code is marginal. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: Your both codes use the same wrong approach in building the name. I gave you a piece of advice. Using `Debug.Print` in order to se with your eyes what that string construction returns...

Comment: Could you write it down as an answer? I am a bit lost, to be honest. Thank you in advance

Comment: I tried your code writihng sth like this:

...
'name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path & Createfolder & "NBU " & fldrtitle & " - Opportunity list.xlsx"

End Sub

But now there is no reaction at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you want this:

```
Function Createfolder() As String
  Dim fso As Object
  Dim fldrtitle As String
  Dim flrdrname As String
  Dim fldrpath As String

  Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  fldrtitle = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
  fldrname = "Pre-planning NBU " & fldrtitle
  fldrpath = "H:\ProfileV2\Desktop\Pre planning NBU\ Alex list new\" & fldrname
  If not fso.FolderExists(fldrpath) Then
      fso.Createfolder (fldrpath)
  End If

  Createfolder = fldrpath
End Function

Sub Save()

  Dim name As String, Custom_Name As String

  name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
  Custom_Name = Createfolder() & "\NBU " & name & " - Opportunity list.xlsx"
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Custom_name, FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

You aren't really gaining anything by separating the folder creation, this would probably be better:

```
Sub Save()

  Dim fso As Object
  Dim fldrtitle As String
  Dim flrdrname As String
  Dim fldrpath As String
  Dim filename As String
  Dim name As String

  'Construct folder name
  fldrtitle = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
  name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value 'looks like this is the same as fldrtitle, could just use same variable below
  fldrname = "Pre-planning NBU " & fldrtitle
  fldrpath = "H:\ProfileV2\Desktop\Pre planning NBU\ Alex list new\" & fldrname

  'Create folder if it doesn't exist
  Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  If not fso.FolderExists(fldrpath) Then
      fso.Createfolder (fldrpath)
  End If

  'Construct filename and save
  filename = fldrpath & "\NBU " & name & " - Opportunity list.xlsx"
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filename, FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA says: Ambiguous name detected pointing the Function Createfolder() line

Comment: Your `Function Createfolder()` does not return anything neither. It must be `Function Createfolder() As String`, or declare`CreateFoder` variable at the module level.

Comment: Have you deleted the old Createfolder Sub?

Comment: Yes pal. Now everything seems to be fine. Thanks